# Connect Pub/Sub to Dataflow Python pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm writing a Dataflow streaming pipeline (*in Python*) that processes emails.
The idea is that, when an email arrives, a Pub/Sub message is published triggering the pipeline that retrieves the email and processes it.
The content of the Pub/Sub message is useless since I just use it to trigger the pipeline.

I'm having some troubles in this last part. I managed to deploy the pipeline  and to connect it to a Pub/Sub topic, but when I try to test it (publishing a message), nothing happens.

I guess I must set a window that "collects" messages and emit them at some point but how should I do that? **Is there a way to say "start the pipeline everytime a new Pub/Sub message is received, ignoring its content"**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem. The issue was due to the import of custom pipeline option from a class that I defined for that purpose. This import prevented the pipeline to be triggered. Removing it I finally managed to trigger the pipeline.

For those who may need it, the incriminated import was

`from engine.user_options import UserOptions`

and the imported class was

```
import apache_beam as beam


class UserOptions(beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--env', type=str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more information about your pipeline and where the emails are stored?

I would recommend you to look at some of the sample pipelines available in Beam.

- [This pipeline reads from PubSub, modifies and writes to PubSub without windowing](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4c693e7aa1ba71fa83370dd383f4bcebe4690b86/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub_it_pipeline.py#L54-L89). This is the simplest one, and it sounds like it's what you need.
- [This pipeline reads from PubSub and applies windowing to get a leaderboard](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/dc2a60036cb1afdc0806fe329dd0737f5aa8e437/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/game/leader_board.py#L309-L347)

If you share more info about your pipeline / code, I can try to iterate on it with you.